# Django - how to remove INFO logs of "channels" package

Tags: python, django, logging, redis, channel

I recently started using the [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package in Django (versions: `channels==3.0.4` and `channels-redis==3.3.1`)

The application is sending massive amount of unwanted logs for each request i make to Django. log for example:

```
{"time": "2023-01-11 16:12:09 UTC", "msg": "HTTP %(method)s %(path)s %(status)s [%(time_taken).2f, %(client)s]", "logger": "edison", "level": "INFO", "log_trace": "/Volumes/dev/venv3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py"}
```

the log seems exactly the same no matter what request i send.

I tried to set the `channels` logging level to ERROR using `logging.getLogger('channels').setLevel(logging.ERROR)` just like i do with other packages but it doesn't help

any ideas what I need to do to remove those logs?

Comment: The channels logger is called `django.channels` not `channels`. Try `logging.getLogger('django.channels').setLevel()`